# React native Not Showing Image About State Function

Tags: react-native

Thank you for viewing this topic :) I am still beginning to learn react native as per about app i want give change picture by clicking button.so at least i was tried to being my own code.as its worked on phone app no error occurred at the things problem is i cannot see image on the app.but button is working. and they show yellow warning message before i changes it later

> The Image Component requires a 'source' property rather than 'src'

at after i change src to source in order correctly and message has disappeared but the image is still not working.

here the source code i wrote it

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,StyleSheet,Image,Button} from 'react-native';



export default function App(){
  const [imageLoc,setImage]=useState({uri:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1280px-React-icon.svg.png"});

  const clickChange = () =>{
      setImage({uri:"https://library.kissclipart.com/20190301/tpq/kissclipart-react-native-clipart-react-native-javascript-65771250223ec746.png"});
  }

  return(
    <View style={styles.div}>
      <Image src={imageLoc.uri} styles={styles.img}/>
      <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button title='Change' onPress={clickChange}/>
    </View>
    </View>
  );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  div: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  img:{
    height:100,
    width:100,
  },
  button:{
    marginTop:15,
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had edited my code check this the problem with your code  is in image tag you are using `styles` it should be `style`

change

```
<Image src={imageLoc.uri} styles={styles.img}/>
```

to

```
 <Image  source={{uri: imageLoc.uri}} style={styles.img}/>
```

Total code is

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,StyleSheet,Image,Button} from 'react-native';
export default function App(){
  const [imageLoc,setImage]=useState({uri:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1280px-React-icon.svg.png"});
  const clickChange = () =>{
      setImage({uri:"https://library.kissclipart.com/20190301/tpq/kissclipart-react-native-clipart-react-native-javascript-65771250223ec746.png"});
  }
  return(
    <View style={styles.div}>
      <Image  source={{uri: imageLoc.uri}} style={styles.img}/>
      <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button title='Change' onPress={clickChange}/>
    </View>
    </View>
  );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  div: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  img:{
    height:100,
    width:100,
  },
  button:{
    marginTop:15,
  }

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: as per your answer i am tried to this still not working.

Comment: made changes you need to replace styles in your image tag to style

Comment: haha thanks for that..even i cant a small error as style tags. what a embrassing :P